# How to create a toast in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a toast message to display in android, but i keep getting an error, it is something to do with the context.

I don't really understand context and why I get this error. my code is below, if anyone could explain how to work around this, and show an example that would be great.

```
public void drawPlayer(Canvas canvas){
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    if(x > (width / 2) + (rectSide / 2)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    x = thePlayer.across;
    y = thePlayer.upDown;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 40, green);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(player, x, y, null);
}




    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        int height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        int leftSide = width/4;
        int rightSide = width - (width/4);

        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // the new image position became where you touched

            x = ev.getX();
            y = ev.getY();

            if(x > rightSide){
                thePlayer.right();
                ///theCrate.right();

            }

            if(x < leftSide){
                thePlayer.left();
                //theCrate.left();
            }

            if(x > leftSide && x < rightSide && y < height/2){
                thePlayer.up();
                //theCrate.up();
            }

            if(x > leftSide && x < rightSide && y > height/2){
                thePlayer.down();

            }
            Draw.this.invalidate();
            // redraw the image at the new position

        }
        return true;
    }

    public void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();


        float startX = (width / 2) - (rectSide / 2);
        float stopX = (width / 2) + (rectSide / 2);
        float startY = (height / 2) - (rectSide / 2);
        float stopY = (height / 2) + (rectSide / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1100; i += 100) {
            float newY = startY + i;
            canvas.drawLine(startX, newY, stopX, newY, green);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1100; i += 100) {

            float newX = startX + i;
            canvas.drawLine(newX, startY, newX, stopY, green);
        }

    }

    public void drawPlayer(Canvas canvas){
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        x = thePlayer.across;
        y = thePlayer.upDown;

        if(x > (width / 2) + (rectSide / 2)){
            Toast.makeText(theContext.getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 40, green);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(player, x, y, null);
    }

    /*public void drawCrate(Canvas canvas){
        x = theCrate.acrossCrate;
        y = theCrate.upDownCrate;

        canvas.drawBitmap(crate, x, y, null);

    }*/

    public void drawCrate(Canvas canvas){



            if (thePlayer.across == theCrate.acrossCrate & thePlayer.upDown == theCrate.upDownCrate) {
                theCrate.right();
                xCrate = theCrate.acrossCrate;
                yCrate = theCrate.upDownCrate;
            }

        else{
            xCrate = theCrate.acrossCrate;
            yCrate = theCrate.upDownCrate;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(xCrate, yCrate, 40, black);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();

        canvas.drawRect(0,0,width/4,height,red);
        canvas.drawRect((width - (width/4)),0,width,height,red);
        canvas.drawRect(width/4,0,(width - (width/4)), height/2, blue);
        canvas.drawRect(width/4,height/2,(width - (width/4)),height,blue);

        drawGrid(canvas);
        drawPlayer(canvas);
        drawCrate(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error logcat

Comment: getApplicationContext is just red

Comment: Does void drawPlayer(Canvas canvas) reside inside an inner class?

Comment: Are you having the problem with the first Toast, or the one with `theContext.getApplicationContext()`?  Also, where is `theContext` defined?  Also, is this code in an Activity, a Fragment, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using *drawPlayer(Canvas canvas)* inside an inner class. In that case if you need access to a context from within another context, then you have to use.

```
getBaseContext();
```

to get the **context**.

```
public void drawPlayer(Canvas canvas){
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    if(x > (width / 2) + (rectSide / 2)){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    x = thePlayer.across;
    y = thePlayer.upDown;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 40, green);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(player, x, y, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you even come about the variable `theContext()`? It's not defined anywhere inside your code.That's why you are are getting the error.
Anyway, is your method in a Fragment or an Activity?
If it is in a Fragment, use

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"this is my Toast message!!! =)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if it's in an Activity, just do:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in the following way To`enter code here

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast Made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if you want to make it for longer time you can use Toast.LENGTH_LONG

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! OP is not complaining about the toast's duration but is getting an error (and fails to share the error). Also please try to make your answer more understandable. `enter code here` is what you get when you press that "code" button but you should now replace "enter code here" with your code ;)